# WPF user controlled grid column width

Tags: wpf, grid, column-width

I've got a grid, currently with three columns.  The first column contains a WrapPanel.  The second column takes up whatever space is left, and the third column is a fixed width.

I want the user to be able to re-distribute the space between the first and second column - that is, some form of dragable division between the two columns, that will resize them accordingly.

Any pointers would be appreciated.  I'm not sure where to start!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to look into a GridSplitter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.aspx

Check out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753302.aspx or http://www.devcurry.com/2010/08/using-gridsplitter-in-windows.html

Comment: Spot on - that's exactly what I'm after! Thanks