# Resizeable multiple TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, drag

I'm going to create some program that resizeable (with drag) multiple Textboxes.

[image: Layout]

But, I don't know how to build this layout. Is there know how to create drag layout?

Comment: I believe you are looking for a datagrid, im assuiming you want the labels to drag with the textboxes though, and in this case the labels are what is dragged not the textbox. Not exactly what you want, but i think it fulfills your purpose

Comment: @GordonAllocman Thank you very much! I'll search about it

Comment: If creating a DataGrid with custom Headers containing TextBoxes doesn't work, I would also recommend looking into an ItemsControl. I've done a lot of Drag/Drop in the past using ItemsControl, but it's a lot more work than just overwriting a DataGrid header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your exact specification is here. But the drawing makes it look like you want *some* cells within the grid to have grab handles for varying width, while others do not. For this purpose, you should be able to use the `GridSplitter` object.

For example:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO36334781GridSplitter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <StackPanel>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
          <p:Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>

            <!-- Offset the splitter visually so it's centered over the gridline -->
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
              <Setter.Value>
                <TranslateTransform X="2.5" Y="0"/>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </p:Style>
          <p:Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
          </p:Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Label1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Label1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Label1" Grid.Column="2"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="A wide textbox here"/>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The above shows a grid with three `TextBox` controls in the middle row, the widths of which can be modified by the user by dragging the `GridSplitter` between each of them. The labels above them (i.e. the `TextBlock` objects) are moved/resized as well, as they share the same column with each respective `TextBox`.

A fourth `TextBox` is shown, spanning three columns in the last row, to show how you can still have other grid elements independent of the splitters. I assume you can modify the basic idea to suit your specific needs.

Note that it's important you provide your specific formatting for the splitter objects, and that they appear *after* the controls they share grid elements with, so that they are above those controls in the z-order.

See also this Stack Overflow question: [WPF user controlled grid column width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5156519)

**Addendum:**

As hinted at in the (now deleted) comments by [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey), it is possible to place splitter controls without them having to share the cell with (and possibly obscuring) other elements in the grid. The following XAML snippet (i.e. just the `Grid` element) shows how that would work:

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <p:Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="5"/>
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"/>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    </p:Style>
    <p:Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    </p:Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Text="Label1" Grid.Column="0"/>
  <TextBlock Text="Label1" Grid.Column="2"/>
  <TextBlock Text="Label1" Grid.Column="4"/>

  <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
  <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
  <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"/>

  <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
  <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>

  <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Text="A wide textbox here"/>
</Grid>
```

The above eliminates the need for the `RenderTransform`, as each `GridSplitter` winds up centered in its own column. The `ResizeBehavior` is set to `PreviousAndNext`, so that dragging the splitter affects not the width of the column in which the splitter is contained, but instead the widths of the columns immediately before and after it.

It's possible that you could apply a `DataGrid` control in this scenario and get it to do what you want. But there's nothing in your question that suggests to me you need the full feature set of a `DataGrid`, or even that you'll be happy with some of the constraints that would involve (such as the way headings are formatted, and whether you can include other fixed-width elements in the layout).